# How to insert data in to two tables based on parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, api, .net-core

I have two Entities

```
public class ProductOption
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int OptionId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(40)]
        public String OptionName { get; set; }
}


public class ProductOptionValue
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ValueId { get; set; }
        public int OptionId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(32)]
        public String ValueName { get; set; }
 }
```

ABOVE Entities

1. Optionid --Primary key(ProductOption table)
2. Optionid  --foreignkey (ProductOptionValue table)

I have 2 model classes

```
 public class ProductOptionRequest
 {
     public string Name { set; get; }
     public List<ProductValuesRequest> productValues { get; set; }
 }

 public class ProductValuesRequest
 {
     public int OptionId { get; set; }
     public string ValueName { get; set;}
 }
```

now I want insert data into those tables

```
public async Task<ReturnString> SaveProductOption(ProductOptionRequest request)
{
            ReturnString returnString = new ReturnString();
            ProductOption details = new ProductOption();
            details.OptionName = request.Name;
            object result = await productOptionRepository.InsertAsync(details, true);
            foreach (ProductValuesRequest valueRequest in request.productValues)
            {
                ProductOptionValue res = new ProductOptionValue();
                res.OptionId = valueRequest.OptionId;
                res.ValueName = valueRequest.ValueName;
                object response = await productOptionValueRepository.InsertAsync(res, true);
            }
            returnString.StringValue = result != null ? $"{request.Name} saved successfully" : "";
            return returnString;                         
  }
```

I wrote the above pattern. but I don't want to pass  `OptionId`. how to write a single insert query without passing `OptionId` parameter. Because its foreign key of `ProductOption` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Try this code please.

```
 public class ProductOptionValue
    {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ValueId { get; set; }
    public int OptionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public String ValueName { get; set; }

    [RelatedField(Table = "ProductOption", ForeignKey = "OptionId", PrimaryKey="Id")]
    public ProductOption ProductOption{ get; set; }
}



    public async Task<ReturnString> SaveProductOption(ProductOptionRequest request)
       {
        ReturnString returnString = new ReturnString();

        foreach (ProductValuesRequest valueRequest in request.productValues)
        {
            ProductOption details = new ProductOption();
            details.OptionName = request.Name;
            ProductOptionValue res = new ProductOptionValue();
            res.ValueName = valueRequest.ValueName;
            res.ProductOption =result ;
            object response = await 
            productOptionValueRepository.InsertAsync(res, true);
          }
            returnString.StringValue = result != null ? $"{request.Name} saved successfully" : "";
         return returnString;          
 }
```

Comment: hi mehmet ordu ! is there any provision to insert in single query with multiple tables

Comment: its showing error like cant convert oject to ProductOption .

Comment: change  res.ProductOption =result;  to   res.ProductOption =details;